# Python3 BeautifulSoup: Remove a portion of HTML and return as soup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to remove a portion of my soup HTML object, concatenate them together and return as one single soup object.

The portion of the HTML object that I want to remove are all the contents within the `span` and `div` tags that contain a certain `class` name.

An example of the HTML is like so, note that they are in a list of `tag` objects:

```
body = [
<div class="content-block">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
,
<div class="content-block>
    <p style="margin-left:30px;">Some content here</p>
    <span class="special_class"> //Remove
       <a class="explanations-link"></a> //Remove
       ... //Remove
    </span> //Remove
</div>
,
 <div class="content-block>
    <p style="margin-left:30px;">Some content here</p>
    <div class="special_class"> //Remove
       <p>Some content here</p> //Remove
       ... //Remove
    </span> //Remove
</div>
]
```

I would like to remove everything inside the `span` and `div` tags that contains the class name `special_class` as highlighted.

My current implementation loops over each `tag` object, and converts them into `str`, and then do a `replace`. After `replace`ing, I concatenate them together as a `str`. It turns out that the `replace` didn't remove any of those tags, despite having matched.

```
text_str = ""

for item in body:
    item_str = str(item)
    span_class_items = item.findAll("span", {"class": "special_class"})
    div_class_items = item.findAll("div", {"class": "special_class"})

    for i in span_class_items:
        item_str.replace(str(i), "")

     for d in div_class_items:
         item_str.replace(str(d), "")

    text_str += item_str

new_soup = BeautifulSoup(text_str, "html.parser")
```

Also, after parsing `text_str` back into a `soup` object, the returned object is not 1 single `soup` object, but still `len` number of items in the `body` list.

What have I missed?

EDIT:

**Attempt** on using `extract()`

```
for item in body:
    span_class_items = item.findAll("span", {"class": "legend-block explanations"})
    div_class_items = item.findAll("div", {"class": "explanations-fancybox"})
    test_item = item

    if len(span_class_items) > 0:
        for s_item in span_class_items:
             test_item.s_item.extract()

     if len(div_class_items) > 0:
         for d_item in div_class_items:
             test_item.d_item.extract()
```

This attempt throws

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract'`

**Attempt** using `replace_with()`

```
for item in body:
    span_class_items = item.findAll("span", {"class": "legend-block explanations"})
    div_class_items = item.findAll("div", {"class": "explanations-fancybox"})
    test_item = item

    if len(span_class_items) > 0:
        for s_item in span_class_items:
            test_item.replace_with(s_item)

     if len(div_class_items) > 0:
         for d_item in div_class_items:
             test_item.replace_with(d_item)
```

This attempt throws

`Cannot replace one element with another when the element to be replaced is not part of a tree.`

Comment: Read about [extract](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)

Comment: @stovfl I replaced `item_str.replace(str(d), "")` with `item.d.extract()` and it throws `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract'` .

Comment: You need the `item`, a `BeautifulSoup object`, not a `str` representation.

Comment: @stovfl yes, i am using a `soup` object, not a `str` representation. It is still throwing `NoneType` error

Comment: You have to use the `tag` name, which is a attribute from the `item object`, e.g. `item.span.extract()`. See at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PartialSlimEmbed) it that's it what you want.

Comment: Where does your `<div class="special_class">` close?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use decompose() method, it's allow to destroy tag from a tree, here is example

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
a_tag = soup.a

soup.i.decompose()

a_tag
# <a href="http://example.com/">I linked to</a>
```

More information you can find here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose